# Button won't show up in app after installed

Tags: java, android, button, barcode-scanner

I tried to build a QR Code scanner, when I installed on apk, the buttton didn't appear to the place that supposed to be.

Here's my code for the button:

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/scan_btn"
    android:layout_width="127dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="359dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="117dp"
    android:text="@string/scan"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="117dp" />
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't Set up the height of the button, 0dp means it won't be visible.

-change it to wrap_content or something of higher dp.

Comment: Thank you sir it works! Sorry for my stupidity hahaha. Can you help me with another questions that I ask? Please, I need to get my project done soon.

Comment: What is the next issue?

Answer (score 0):

You kept your height to 0dp. Is it constrained vertically?

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake. Its already fix by the vote answer :)